# WPF and XP, 2000 etc. being sure?

Tags: .net, wpf, frameworks

How can I sure that WPF is compatible in XP or an older OS. Is the only thing is Framework version or that could be any other things that must be installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've successfully installed the relevant version of the framework (3.0 or above for WPF) it should be fine. However, as Darin pointed out in the comments, .NET 3.0 and higher are not supported on Windows 2000... so you can't use WPF there.

XP supports all versions of .NET, however - so long as you have the appropriate service pack. (For example, .NET 4 requires SP3.)

Comment: No, .NET 3.0 cannot be installed on Windows 2000 as it contains WCF which relies on the kernel mode `http.sys` which is not part of this operating system.

Comment: @Darin: Gosh, really? Will investigate further - I really thought it was okay. (20 seconds later) Yup, you're right. Will edit.